Nginx does not proxy_pass to the foreign IP
I have two OpenVZ containers running Centos 7.9 on two different servers connected via LAN. First of them running my backend application and the second one I want to run nginx (nginx/1.27.0) as a reverse proxy for that application. First container has IP 192.168.168.1 and the second one - 192.168.168.2 So I'm trying to run nginx and configure location with the "proxy_pass" directive to 192.168.168.1
But it does not work for me. If I use for proxy_pass directive any of IPs from my second container (where nginx is running) like 127.0.0.1, 192.168.168.2 or my IP from the WAN connection - it works. Ofcource it works with the application copy I have to run on my second container to test this.
But when I change target for "proxy_pass" directive to 192.168.168.1 or WAN IP form my first container it does not.
I got Bad Gateway error. The interesting thing that with disabled firewalls I can not see with tcpdump a single packet nginx should try to send to the destination I give him. It seems like nginx just do not accept any foreign IP as a target here.
Maybe I just missed something, but I failed to find any clue in nginx logs and documentation.
To verify that I have no any port blocked or something like that, I started on my second container (where nginx is) a simpleproxy with the next parameters:
simpleproxy -L 127.0.0.1:8011 -R 192.168.168.1:8012 

It listens on port 8011 and proxies requests to the port 8012 on my first container, where my aplication is. Then I gave nginx target for proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:8011 and all works fine.
Part of my nginx configuration:
upstream dev02_relay {
     server 192.168.168.1:8012 fail_timeout=10s; #it does not work
     #server 127.0.0.1:8011 fail_timeout=10s;
 }

location / {

                proxy_cache dev02-relay;
                proxy_cache_valid  200 302  5m;
                proxy_cache_valid  404      1m;

                proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

                proxy_pass            http://dev02_relay;
                proxy_read_timeout    90;
                proxy_connect_timeout 90;
                proxy_redirect        off;
                proxy_set_header      Host $host;
                proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header      Proxy "";

                add_header X-Cache-Status $upstream_cache_status;

            }

And nginx  error log sais :
2024/11/04 13:27:57 [crit] 171248#171248: *16 connect() to 192.168.168.1:8012 failed (22: Invalid argument) while connecting to upstream, ...
If I change just target IP for proxy_pass for the one of locals - all is OK.

Do you have SELinux enabled on your containers?

No. Selinux is disabled.
